# bootstrap mobile device keyboard showing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Higchart graph with bootstrap datepicker. I have a texbox for date. When I click the tectbox for choosing date, keyboard is opening and showing some dates which I choose before. My script is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#date').datepicker({ //# ile id üzerinden yaparsanız yanlızca bir input çalışır 
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd", //dd-mm-yyyy
            autoclose: true,
            weekStart: 1,
            "disableTouchKeyboard": true
            }).load('show', function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var curr_date = today.getDate();
        var curr_month = today.getMonth()+1;
        var curr_year = today.getFullYear();
        var currentDate = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
        $(this).val(currentDate);
      });
       });

</script>
```

Where I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**not sure but this might help**

```
$('#date').datepicker({ //# ile id üzerinden yaparsanız yanlızca bir input çalışır 
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd", //dd-mm-yyyy
            autoclose: true,
            showOnFocus: false,
            })
```

Comment: but that will give your input box grey color of disabled

Comment: I did not do disable. I adjust it for readonly. I can choose date still

Comment: okz i was facing similar problem in bootstrap datetimepicker and problem got solved by above solution .

Answer (score 0):

Just also add attribute readonly in datepicker.

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    format: "dd-M-yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    disableTouchKeyboard: true,
    Readonly: true
}).attr("readonly", "readonly");
```